# Delete parts of strings in an array depending on character (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, delete-operator

I have an array with string elements and I want to delete parts of each string. The print_r($myarray) gives:

```
Array([0] => WSN4/temp [1]=>WSN5/temp [2] =>WSN7/humi ... [n]=>WSNn/humi)
```

I want to delete all characters from "/" until the end. The output of the newarray should be:

```
Array([0]=>WSN4 [1]=>WSN5 [2]=>WSN7 ... [n]=>WSNn)
```

I would be thankful, if someone has an easy solution or any advice to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this answer your question?

```
<?php
$items = [
    'WSN4/temp',
    'WSN5/temp',
    'WSN7/humi',
    'WSNn/humi',
];

$target = array_map(function ($item) {
    return strstr($item, '/', true);
}, $items);

print_r($target);
```